# Openshift Mounting MYSQL and PHP containes under on pod

Tags: openshift

I am building a template by adapting this one (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift-evangelists/wordpress-quickstart/master/templates/classic-standalone.json) which requires two persistent storages. I am trying to do the same with just one but for some reason I am getting several errors. Can someone verify that my json is correct?

```
{
    "kind": "Template",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "wordpress-classic-standalone",
    "annotations": {
            "openshift.io/display-name": "WordPress (Classic / Standalone)",
        "description": "Creates a WordPress installation with separate MySQL database instance. Requires that two persistent volumes be available. If a ReadWriteMany persistent volume type is available and used, WordPress can be scaled to multiple replicas and the deployment strategy switched to Rolling to permit rolling deployments on restarts.",
        "tags": "quickstart,php,wordpress",
            "iconClass": "icon-php"
    }
    },
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "APPLICATION_NAME",
            "description": "The name of the WordPress instance.",
            "value": "my-wordpress-site",
            "from": "[a-zA-Z0-9]",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "name": "QUICKSTART_REPOSITORY_URL",
            "description": "The URL of the quickstart Git repository.",
            "value": "https://github.com/openshift-evangelists/wordpress-quickstart",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "name": "WORDPRESS_VOLUME_SIZE",
            "description": "Size of the persistent volume for Wordpress.",
            "value": "1Gi",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "name": "WORDPRESS_VOLUME_TYPE",
            "description": "Type of the persistent volume for Wordpress.",
            "value": "ReadWriteOnce",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "name": "WORDPRESS_DEPLOYMENT_STRATEGY",
            "description": "Type of the deployment strategy for Wordpress.",
            "value": "Recreate",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "name": "WORDPRESS_MEMORY_LIMIT",
            "description": "Amount of memory available to WordPress.",
            "value": "512Mi",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "name": "DATABASE_VOLUME_SIZE",
            "description": "Size of the persistent volume for the database.",
            "value": "1Gi",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "name": "DATABASE_MEMORY_LIMIT",
            "description": "Amount of memory available to the database.",
            "value": "512Mi",
            "required": true
        },
    {
        "description": "The name of the database user.",
        "name": "DATABASE_USERNAME",
        "from": "user[a-f0-9]{8}",
        "generate": "expression"
    },
    {
        "description": "The password for the database user.",
        "name": "DATABASE_PASSWORD",
        "from": "[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}",
        "generate": "expression"
    },
        {
            "name": "MYSQL_VERSION",
            "description": "The version of the MySQL database.",
            "value": "5.7",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "name": "PHP_VERSION",
            "description": "The version of the PHP builder.",
            "value": "7.0",
            "required": true
        }
    ],
    "objects": [
        {
            "kind": "ImageStream",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}-img",
                "labels": {
                    "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "BuildConfig",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}",
                "labels": {
                    "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "triggers": [
                    {
                        "type": "ConfigChange"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ImageChange"
                    }
                ],
                "source": {
                    "type": "Git",
                    "git": {
                        "uri": "${QUICKSTART_REPOSITORY_URL}"
                    }
                },
                "strategy": {
                    "type": "Source",
                    "sourceStrategy": {
                        "from": {
                            "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                            "namespace": "openshift",
                            "name": "php:${PHP_VERSION}"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "output": {
                    "to": {
                        "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                        "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}-img:latest"
                    },
                    "imageLabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "io.k8s.display-name",
                            "value": "WordPress"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "io.k8s.description",
                            "value": "WordPress application and S2I builder."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "io.openshift.s2i.scripts-url",
                            "value": "image:///opt/app-root/s2i"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "io.s2i.scripts-url",
                            "value": "image:///opt/app-root/s2i"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "io.openshift.tags",
                            "value": "builder,php,wordpress"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "DeploymentConfig",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}",
                "labels": {
                    "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "strategy": {
                    "type": "${WORDPRESS_DEPLOYMENT_STRATEGY}"
                },
                "triggers": [
                    {
                        "type": "ConfigChange"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ImageChange",
                        "imageChangeParams": {
                            "automatic": true,
                            "containerNames": [
                                "wordpress"
                            ],
                            "from": {
                                "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                                "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}-img:latest"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "replicas": 1,
                "selector": {
                    "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}",
                    "deploymentconfig": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                },
                "template": {
                    "metadata": {
                        "labels": {
                            "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}",
                            "deploymentconfig": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                        }
                    },
                    "spec": {
                        "volumes": [
                            {
                                "name": "data",
                                "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                                    "claimName": "${APPLICATION_NAME}-data"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "containers": [
                            {
                                "name": "wordpress",
                                "image": "${APPLICATION_NAME}-img",
                                "ports": [
                                    {
                                        "containerPort": 8080,
                                        "protocol": "TCP"
                                    }
                                ],
                "resources": {
                                    "limits": {
                                        "memory": "${WORDPRESS_MEMORY_LIMIT}"
                    }
                                },
                "readinessProbe": {
                    "failureThreshold": 3,
                    "httpGet": {
                    "path": "/wp-admin/install.php",
                    "port": 8080,
                    "scheme": "HTTP",
                    "httpHeaders": [
                        {
                        "name": "X-Forwarded-Proto",
                        "value": "https"
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    "periodSeconds": 10,
                    "successThreshold": 1,
                    "timeoutSeconds": 1
                },
                "livenessProbe": {
                    "failureThreshold": 3,
                    "httpGet": {
                    "path": "/wp-admin/install.php",
                    "port": 8080,
                    "scheme": "HTTP",
                    "httpHeaders": [
                        {
                        "name": "X-Forwarded-Proto",
                        "value": "https"
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    "periodSeconds": 10,
                    "successThreshold": 1,
                    "timeoutSeconds": 1
                },
                                "env": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE",
                                        "value": "wordpress"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "MYSQL_USER",
                                        "value": "${DATABASE_USERNAME}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
                                        "value": "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "MYSQL_HOST",
                                        "value": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "MYSQL_TABLE_PREFIX",
                                        "value": "wp_"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "volumeMounts": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "data",
                                        "mountPath": "/opt/app-root/src",
                                        "subPath": "wordpress"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "mysql",
                                "image": "mysql",
                                "ports": [
                                    {
                                        "containerPort": 3306,
                                        "protocol": "TCP"
                                    }
                                ],
                "resources": {
                                    "limits": {
                                        "memory": "${DATABASE_MEMORY_LIMIT}"
                    }
                                },
                "readinessProbe": {
                  "timeoutSeconds": 1,
                  "initialDelaySeconds": 5,
                  "exec": {
                    "command": [ "/bin/sh", "-i", "-c",
                      "MYSQL_PWD=\"$MYSQL_PASSWORD\" mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u $MYSQL_USER -D $MYSQL_DATABASE -e 'SELECT 1'"]
                  }
                },
                "livenessProbe": {
                  "timeoutSeconds": 1,
                  "initialDelaySeconds": 30,
                  "tcpSocket": {
                    "port": 3306
                  }
                },
                                "env": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE",
                                        "value": "wordpress"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "MYSQL_USER",
                                        "value": "${DATABASE_USERNAME}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
                                        "value": "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "volumeMounts": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "data",
                                        "mountPath": "/var/lib/mysql/data",
                                        "subPath": "mysql"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "Service",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}",
                "labels": {
                    "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "name": "8080-tcp",
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "port": 8080,
                        "targetPort": 8080
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "3306-tcp",
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "port": 3306,
                        "targetPort": 3306
                    }
                ],
                "selector": {
                    "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}",
                    "deploymentconfig": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "Route",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}",
                "labels": {
                    "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "host": "",
                "to": {
                    "kind": "Service",
                    "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}",
                    "weight": 100
                },
                "port": {
                    "targetPort": 8080
                },
                "tls": {
                    "termination": "edge",
                    "insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy": "Allow"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${APPLICATION_NAME}-data",
                "labels": {
                    "app": "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "accessModes": [
                    "ReadWriteOnce"
                ],
                "resources": {
                    "requests": {
                        "storage": "${DATABASE_VOLUME_SIZE}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The errors look like this:

```
10:29:32 AM my-wordpress-site-1 Replication Controller  Normal  Successful delete   Deleted pod: my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst
10:26:55 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Normal  Created     Created container
2 times in the last 5 minutes
10:26:54 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Normal  Pulled  Successfully pulled image "172.30.254.23:5000/test/my-wordpress-site-img@sha256:09e48c3c1530b0b3472c39a46bddffcd1b756334db9e6bf1c0f77ff58d2662da"
2 times in the last 5 minutes
10:26:53 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Normal  Pulling     pulling image "172.30.254.23:5000/test/my-wordpress-site-img@sha256:09e48c3c1530b0b3472c39a46bddffcd1b756334db9e6bf1c0f77ff58d2662da"
2 times in the last 5 minutes
10:26:53 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Normal  Killing     Killing container with id docker://wordpress:pod "my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst_test(d8f11f11-ac4c-11e7-a41e-0ab8769191d3)" container "wordpress" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
10:26:52 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Warning Unhealthy   Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.131.132.199:8080/wp-admin/install.php: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2 times in the last 5 minutes
10:26:52 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Warning Unhealthy   Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.131.132.199:8080/wp-admin/install.php: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2 times in the last 5 minutes
10:26:41 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Warning Unhealthy   Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
10:26:41 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Warning Unhealthy   Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
10:26:39 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Warning Failed sync     Error syncing pod
4 times in the last 10 minutes
10:26:39 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Warning Failed  Error: Error response from daemon: {"message":"create 22cfae77db503968720c442cd52064146826e208e15d0a02de94d321bf342127: mkdir /var/lib/docker/volumes/22cfae77db503968720c442cd52064146826e208e15d0a02de94d321bf342127: permission denied"}
10:26:36 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Normal  Pulled  Successfully pulled image "mysql"
2 times in the last 5 minutes
10:26:31 AM my-wordpress-site-1-qwsst   Pod Normal  Pulling     pulling image "mysql"
2 times in the last
```

Comment: The ``testing-standalone.json`` template in the same directory already does it using one volume together in one pod. Why aren't you using that? The repository https://github.com/openshift-evangelists/php-quickstart also has a simpler generic example for deploying a PHP+MySQL site with one volume if don't actually want WordPress.

Comment: BTW, if you have been playing around, make sure you have deleted the prior application instance completely, including any existing persistent volume claims.

Comment: Well that indeed solves it. I feel silly trying to build something that was available. I wish that openshift would have a simple tutorial guide that imports the php-quickstart template. It makes it super easy to transition from my openshift 2 setup.